# Passing function parameter to ajax data return undefined index error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm working on a song site, where you can rate songs, singers etc, and you also have the option to add them to your favourites.

After a while I've noticed when I add/remove song/singer from my favourites, I pretty much repeate the same `ajax` request multiple times, only with a different feedback message, so I decided to create a separate `function` of that request, and in other methods I just call this.

For this I set things such as the route of the button, feedback, message etc in the parameter of the `favourite` function, as you can see below.

The `feedback()` function is not really important I believe, I just shared if someone would like to know how it looks like, or if they'd actually find it important anyway.

```
function feedback($feedback_route,$message_route,$alert_class,$message){
    $($feedback_route).removeClass("d-none");
    $($feedback_route).addClass($alert_class);
    $($feedback_route).addClass("animated fadeIn");
    $($message_route).html($message);
    setTimeout(() => {
        $($feedback_route).addClass("animated fadeOut");
    }, 2000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        $($feedback_route).addClass("d-none");
        $($feedback_route).removeClass($alert_class);
        $($message_route).html("");
    }, 2500);
}

function favourite($ajax_route,$post,$button_route,$event,$feedback_route,
        $message_route,$success_message,$error_message){
        $.ajax({
            url: $ajax_route,
            type: "post",
            data: {
                $post: $($button_route).attr("value"),
                event:$event
            },
            success: (data) => {
                 feedback($feedback_route,$message_route,"alert-success",$success_message);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    $($button_route).replaceWith(data);
                }, 2500);
            },
            error: () => {
                feedback($feedback_route,$message_route,"alert-danger",$error_message);
            }
        });
    }

//-------------------------------ADD SONG TO FAVOURITES-----------------------------
$("#song-info-container #song-container").on("click","#add-to-favourites", () => {
    favourite(
        "ajax/song-favourite.php",
        "songID","#song-info-container #song-container #add-to-favourites",
        "add","#song-info-container #song-container .feedback",
        "#song-info-container #song-container #message",
        "Added!","Failed to add!"
        );
    $("#song-info-container #song-container .feedback").removeClass("animated fadeOut");
});
```

Here's how the original `ajax` request looks like:

```
$("#song-info-container #song-container").on("click","#add-to-favourites", () => {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax/song-favourite.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            songID: $("#song-info-container #song-container #add-to-favourites").attr("value"),
            event:"add"
        },
        success: (data) => {
            feedback("#song-info-container #song-container .feedback",
                "#song-info-container #song-container #message","alert-success","Added!");
            setTimeout(() => {
                $("#song-info-container #song-container #add-to-favourites").replaceWith(data);
            }, 2500);
        },
        error: () => {
            feedback("#song-info-container #song-container .feedback",
                "#song-info-container #song-container #message","alert-danger","Failed to add!");
        }
    });
    $("#song-info-container #song-container .feedback").removeClass("animated fadeOut");
});
```

And now the actual problem: first I thought it actually works, because the feedback appears with the correct message, but after it disappears(*see in the `setTimeOut` function*), the following message appears:

`Notice: Undefined index: songID in G:\x\htdocs\AniSong\ajax\song-favourite.php on line 9`

So the data which is also set in the parameter of the `favourite` function is not being passed to the other file.

Does someone know why this happens?

Or can I not do an `ajax` request like this in the first place?

PS: Sorry if the title doesn't make sense, didn't really know how it should be asked.

Comment: I don't see how this answers my question. It doesn't help at all.

Comment: Just a note, you seem to be mixing on how a variable from `php` looks like in your `js` variables. Regardless, it would be really nice if you could also highlight where exactly is **on line 9**

Comment: The main difference I'm seeing between the "original" version and the "non-working" version is that the original version has a parameter called `songID`, and the new version has a parameter called `$post`.  If you're not sending a parameter called `songID`, and your server-side code is looking for a parameter called `songID`, then doesn't that immediately explain the error?

Comment: @David But I set the name of that parameter when I call the method. `favourite(...,"songID",...)`  The way I name these parameters doesn't matter at all as far as I know. But I just changed it just in case that'd matter, but it changed nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

Comment: I already got an answer, why are you still marking it as a duplicate? That question also has nothing to do with mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do what you're expecting:

```
{
    $post: $($button_route).attr("value"),
    event: $event
}
```

This won't replace `$post` with the string value you're passing to the function.  This gives the property the literal name `$post`.  Check the network tab of your browser's debugging tools to see what you're actually sending to the server.  There is no `songID` property.

A quick test to validate:

```js
let $foo = 'test';
console.log({$foo: 'baz'});
```

If you want to dynamically send this information, you'll need to modify your data structure to do that.  Similar to how you have a dynamic "event", you'll now need a dynamic "post".  Something like:

```
{
    post: $post,
    value: $($button_route).attr("value"),
    event: $event
}
```

Then in your server-side code you'd change your logic to examine the `post` parameter to see what field you're updating, or whatever such logic you're using server-side.

---

Alternatively, it just occurs to me that you could potentially create a dynamic property name.  Consider something like this:

```js
let $post = 'songID';
let data = {
    event: 'add'
};
data[$post] = 'test value';
console.log(data);
```

It's up to you which you think is more complex vs. which is easier for you to support.